# How to implement a minimax algorithm in a chess-like game?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, chess, minimax

I am currently trying to write an AI that plays a chess-like game. For this I am using a variant of the minimax algorithm that iterates through every possible move and then assumes for a depth of N that the opponent (and they) will play optimally for N moves. The pseudocode for this looks is as follows:

```
public string GenerateDepth1Move()
    {
       
        int max = -INFINITY;
        string bestMove;
        List<string> moves = PossibleMoves(colour);
        foreach (string s in moves)
        {
            int temp += Move(s, colour);
            if(temp > max)
            {
                max = temp;
                bestMove = s;
            }
        }

       return bestMove;

    }
```

When 'Move' is called it detects whether a piece has been taken, and then generates a score for that piece, which is saved into the variable 'temp'. For a depth of 2 I simply call another Depth1 method but change the colour. For a depth of 3 I call this again for the next theoretical move the AI will make. This works well enough, but at depth 4 it ceases to function in a logical manner.

This is because the algorithm assumes that the 'optimal' move is greedy (i.e. the optimal move is taking whatever the highest valued piece is, which is not necessarily the best move in the game itself as you may get immediately taken back and lose a more valuable piece in the process). To remedy this I tried calling my Depth2 method inside a Depth3 or Depth4 method, but what it produced was equally illogical and bad at the game. I am not sure why this is the case, but leaving it at Depth3 produces the most robust AI when this should not be the case.

Have I failed to understand the nature of a minimax-like algorithm? How can I improve my algorithm so that a higher N value leads to better play?

Comment: `int temp += Move(s, colour);` makes no sense. I think you wanted `=` instead of `+=`.

Comment: Other than that, the pseudo-code looks plausibly correct for choosing the `s` that causes `Move` to return the largest value. But that's not all there is to minimax. You haven't shown the actual minimax code.

Answer (score 0):

MiniMax is good with a ***recursive*** implementation. You can find an example in [this great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l-hh51ncgDI). Implement Minimax iteratively and write n times the depth 1 function for depth n does not follow the Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) rule.
Implementation in Python :

```
def minimax(pos, depth, alpha, beta, maximizingPlayer) :
# maximizingPlayer = True if White2Play and False is Black2Play

if depth == 0 or game_is_finished(board) or can_t_move(board) :
    return evaluate(board)                                     # <- zero ground for recusivity

if maximizingPlayer :
    maxEval = -infinity(or a number smaller than your smallest evaluation)
    for child in child_of_position(board) :
        evalu = minimax(child, depth - 1, alpha, beta, False)  # recursivity
        maxEval = max(maxEval, evalu)
        alpha = max(alpha, evalu)
        if beta <= alpha :
            break
    return maxEval

else :
    minEval = infinity(or a number larger than your largest evaluation)
    for child in child_of_position(board) :
        evalu = minimax(child, depth - 1, alpha, beta, True)    # recursivity
        minEval = min(minEval, evalu)
        alpha = min(alpha, evalu)
        if beta <= alpha :
            break
    return minEval
```

In the beginning, call minimax with alpha = -infinity and beta = infinity.
To generate the best move, use a minimax_root algorithm.
Note: you can use a [NegaMax](https://www.chessprogramming.org/Negamax) algorithm, shorter than Minimax (but need to evaluate the position from the player's point of view, not white's point of view like in Minimax).

Comment: My problem is that I'm having difficulty understanding how the algorithm recognises the changing nature of the board. With each theoretical move made the positions on the board are different. How does the algorithm account for this?

Comment: Also, how is the minimax() function even giving a number of the variable evalu? And what does "return evaluate(board)" mean? I don't see an evaluate() function? Shouldn't it just return a move?

Comment: Evaluata(board) return a number. this number represent a evaluation of the position. So it will choose the best evaluation for the player (max or min function).

Comment: And for changing board, child_of_position(board) returns all the new possibles boards from a given board.